# Nginx error log doesn't list 404s

Tags: nginx

Tell me if I'm going mad here...

I've got a basic PHP 5.6 website on Nginx 1.10.3

For some reason, it doesn't log 404s to the /var/log/nginx/error.log file declared in nginx.conf. The PHP errors end up there just fine but 404s don't.

Here's the server config:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name staging.domain.co.uk;
root /var/www/domain.co.uk;
index index.php;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/staging.domain.co.uk.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/staging.domain.co.uk.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

error_page 404 /pnf.php;
```

}

Also, the nginx.conf is...

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Can someone please tell me if I'm going mad?! All I want to know is why it's not listing 404s at all!

TIA!

Comment: Your `try_files $uri =404;` statement explicitly generates the 404 response. It is not an error.

Comment: Super, thanks @RichardSmith.

When I changed it to:

`try_files $uri last;`

then it generated the 404 error in the log file as desired.

Comment: `try_files $uri last;` is incorrect. It will redirect non-existing files to `{$uri}last` and will generate 404 if `{$uri}last` doest not exist

Answer (score 0):

Because this directive:

`error_page 404 /pnf.php;`

Causes Nginx to redirect 404s to that URL and return a 302 response code to the client.